# Issue when escaping '%' character

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an image table with a name column. The value inside the name column may contain a percentage sign, which by itself is a wild card character when using the like operator. I currently have the following relevant values in the name column: "a%" and "blah%blah".

I do not get any results, as expected, when performing:

```
select name from image where name like '\%'
```

When performing the following, I am getting 2 of the above mentioned records:

```
select name from image where name like '%\%'
```

I understand why I am getting the record with "a%" as the name. However, I do not understand why I am getting "blah%blah". If "blah%blah" had a percentage character as the last character, it would make sense, but it does not.

Am I doing something wrong here or is this a MySQL bug?

Comment: Can you provide an SQLFiddle with this behavior? I cannot reproduce this on my system (mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.0.19-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper).

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8b836f/1

Comment: try this: `WHERE name like '%\%%'`

Comment: MySQL bug: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=74901

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in [this](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=74901) bug, you need to use another collation as a workaround:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1994f1/1)

**Using utf8_unicode_ci colation**:

```
CREATE TABLE image
    (`id` int, `name` varchar(55) collate utf8_unicode_ci)
;

INSERT INTO image
    (`id`, `name`)
VALUES
    (1, 'a%'),
    (2, 'blah%blah')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
  name
FROM
  image
WHERE name like '%\%'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1994f1/1/0)**:

```
|      name |
|-----------|
|        a% |
| blah%blah |
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d63f/1)

**Using utf8_general_ci collation**:

```
CREATE TABLE image
    (`id` int, `name` varchar(55) collate utf8_general_ci)
;

INSERT INTO image
    (`id`, `name`)
VALUES
    (1, 'a%'),
    (2, 'blah%blah')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
  name
FROM
  image
WHERE name like '%\%'
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7d63f/1/0)**:

```
| name |
|------|
|   a% |
```

Comment: Thanks. I figured this might be a bug but wasn't able to find it. At least I know my gray cell logic circuits are operating correctly.